# Select element has other width than silbling, bootstrap spacing overshooting

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am styling an inputform with bootstrap-4. I've got an input-field and a select-field. Both have the class col, but different spacing classes, but the select-field is a bit smaller.

When I use the class col-6 for both fields, they have the same length, but then I can't create spacing, which is needed for my case. When i add spacing, one of the items just get moved to the next line.

JS-Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/p81z7Lfg/1/

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <input type="text" class="col mr-1" value="1">
    <input type="text" class="col ml-1" value="2">
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <input type="text" class="col mr-1" value="3">
    <select class="col ml-1">
      <option selected>4</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="row"></div>

  <div class="row">
    <input type="text" class="col mr-1" value="1">
    <input type="text" class="col ml-1" value="2">
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <input type="text" class="col-6 mr-1" value="3">
    <select class="col-6 ml-1">
      <option selected>4</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

A bootstrap solution would be really fine, because of project consistent styling and coding, I don't want to use own css in the middle of bootstrap.

Thank you.

Comment: Why you want to use `col-6`. Just you the same syntax which is used for second `row` i.e without `col-6` .

Comment: I don't want to use col-6, but i haven't found another way to achieve the same width for the select and the input-field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default Bootstrap v4 form markup:

```
div.row 
  div.col
    input.form-control
  div.col
    input.form-control
div.row
  div.col
    select.form-control
      option
      option
      ...
  div.col
    any-other-form-element.form-control
```

Obviously you can swap `.col`s for any other `.col-*-*` according to how you want them to display at various screen widths.

**But you can also swap `.row`s for `.form-row`s, as [stated in docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/forms/#form-row):**

> You may also swap `.row` for `.form-row`, a variation of our standard grid row that overrides the default column gutters for tighter and more compact layouts.

See it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/oqj2e7pz/).